# Microsoft-cognitive Face API invalid subscription key

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I tried both 'Key 1' and 'Key 2' of Face API from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/ in this.
But am getting the following error. How can I get a new API key? or how can I fix this problem?

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": "Unspecified",
>       "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."
>     }
>   }

Comment: Hey @Ahmad did you solve the problem? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that:

1. You've specified the correct endpoint.  The endpoint is shown on the same [my_apis](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/) link you included.  An API key for one region/property will not work in another.
2. Your key has not expired.  The remaining days will be shown on that same link.

Comment: I Have the same problem too. I tried both keys and I  have 28 days left

Comment: Can you try [this](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395248) page?  Launch an API Test Console by clicking on the correct region (WestUS, etc.).  You will need to enter the API key in the edit box on the second page.